# Problem with the arithmetics in the bash scripting

Tags: bash, command-line, ffmpeg, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to cut a video into 2-minute clips using FFMpeg. I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
COUNTER=0
BEG=0
MIN=`ffmpeg -i ${1} 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | cut -d ":" -f 2`
echo $MIN
((MIN=MIN-2))
before_last_dot=${1%.*};
while [ $COUNTER -lt $MIN ]; do
    ((BEG=COUNTER*60))
    echo "MIN:${MIN}"
    echo "ffmpeg -sameq -i ${1} -ss ${BEG} -t 120 ${before_last_dot}.${COUNTER}.wmv"
    ((COUNTER=COUNTER+2))
done
```

`echo "ffmpeg -sameq -i ${1} -ss ${BEG} -t 120 ${before_last_dot}.${COUNTER}.wmv"` should be `ffmpeg -sameq -i ${1} -ss ${BEG} -t 120 ${before_last_dot}.${COUNTER}.wmv`. I print it to check it. ${1} is the video name.

But the problem is, `((COUNTER=COUNTER+2))` or `((COUNTER+=2))`never works! `COUNTER` is always 0, `BEG` is always 0 too. `((MIN=MIN-2))` never works too.

I tried to replace `((MIN=MIN-2))` with `let "MIN-=2"` I get an error: `let: not found`

I+ve double checked but still don't know why. I'm getting gray hair on this.

Comment: Have you tried running the script with debugging flag -x? `#!/bin/sh -x` It will echo result of the each command

Comment: Perhaps you're not even running bash? Try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Martin: You have a sharp eye! `#!/bin/bash` works! Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: I still dont know the difference between `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @DocWiki: There are many shells, bash, the Bourne Again Shell, is just one of them. `/bin/sh` is the default, usually the most basic on an installation, shell scripts that are simple default to it, as it is practically always there - you can not assume it is a given shell though.

Comment: The are many different shells in the linux world. `bin/sh` is a link to the default implementation, which is dash shell on the ubuntu (for few last editions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `((MIN=MIN-2))` syntax that you're using is a `bash`-specific feature.

I don't have Ubuntu 10.10 to hand to test with, but I'd guess that your `/bin/sh` is not `bash`, but a smaller and simpler shell with only the basic features required by POSIX.  (In which case, `((MIN=MIN-2))` probably launches a sub-shell, which launches a sub-shell, which does nothing but set a variable `MIN` to the string `MIN-2` and then exit.)

Try `#!/bin/bash` on the first line instead.

Comment: Yeah. I `cd /bin` and see `sh -> dash`.